# Haskell - where "clause" multiple variables

Tags: haskell

I am trying to pick up some basic Haskell skills and wrote the following code:

```
pennypincherRec :: [Int] -> Int
pennypincherRec (x : xs) | deducted <= 19900 = deducted + rest
                        | otherwise = rest
                        where deducted = discount x
                              rest = pennypincherRec xs
```

It works if I replace the "rest" with "pennypincherRec xs" and remove the last line.

With the code above, it gives: parse error on input `rest'

So how do I use the where clause for multiple variables?

Comment: Double check you don't have TAB characters in your source file.

Comment: @chi so what should I have? 4 spaces for each tab?

Comment: Yep, that was it... so I had tabs from the beginning on the line until "rest"

Comment: Don't use tabs at all; the required amount of space is determined by the structure of the preceding line, not any fixed number of spaces.